# Want to refresh cache in Redis using Spring boot Considering multiple pods

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, redis, refresh

Currently I am using annotation @CacheEvict using cron job, after that reloading again using new calls, but not happy with this approach as I have multiple nods.

My requirement is

1. Reload cache with new data after a certain time limit.
2. Should be working in multiple nodes.

Looking for a elegant design.

Comment: Read your question five times and still I can't understand from it what exactly is the problem. Why are you not happy with the current approach? With what data do you want to populate the cache after it's been cleared? What do you want to be working on multiple nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using cache manager?

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-multiple-cache-managers

1. Spring @CacheEvict annotation is used to evict cache.
2. The @CacheEvict is used at method level.
3. The @Cacheable annotation sets the value in cache and on the contrary @CacheEvict evicts the cache.
4. At one method we can use @Cacheable to cache result and at another method we can use @CacheEvict to evict cache.
5. The @CacheEvict annotation is introduced in Spring 3.1.

The @CacheEvict has following attributes.

1. String[] cacheNames
   Cache names to evict.
2. String[] value
   Alias for cacheNames.
3. String key
   SpEL expression for computing the key dynamically.
4. String keyGenerator
   The bean name of the custom KeyGenerator to use.
5. String cacheManager
   The bean name of the custom CacheManager. It is used to create default CacheResolver if none is set already.
6. String cacheResolver
   The bean name of the custom CacheResolver to use.
7. String condition
   SpEL expression used for making the cache eviction operation conditional.
8. boolean allEntries
   If true, all the entries inside the cache are removed.
9. boolean beforeInvocation

If true, the cache eviction will occur before the method is invoked.

Comment: It will not help to resolve auto cahce refresh in case of multiple nodes

Answer (score 0):

I think you take the risk to never be satisfied by a solution crafted inside your application code to solve an architectural design problematic of the deployment of the application.
If you need to control the behavior of a variable set of nodes, you better have to design a small independent tool (e.g. in the form of a micro-service) that will receive "meta" requests and do the right thing: calling @CacheEvict and then @Cache entry points of all nodes in the right order. The list of nodes and the list of entry points to be called could be easily defined in parameter files or in a datasource.
You can also make your pods listening to a stream of events or an AMQP broadcaster.